# ffmpeg for screencapture with audio taken by the speakers

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, microphone, speakers

I discovered that it is possible to use **ffmpeg** to make **screencaptures**, here is an example that saves the video at 30 fps starting from the coordinates 100,200 to 1280x720:

```
ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 100 -offset_y 200 -video_size 1280x720 draw_mouse 0 -i desktop YOUR_NAME_HERE.mp4
```

I would also like to capture the audio though of the **speakers** and not of the microphone, in fact it is possible to capture the audio of the microphone by adding the following information:

```
... audio = "NAME_MIC" ...
```

However, if I enter the name of the audio output it does not capture the sound.

Do you know how to solve?
Thank you

Comment: You need to check what audio outputs are available by running `ffmpeg -f dshow -list_devices true -i dummy`

Answer (score 0):

if I had already tried, here's what it returns:

```
[dshow @ 0000000000420680] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 0000000000420680]  "FaceTime HD Camera (Display)"
[dshow @ 0000000000420680]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_05ac&pi d_1112&mi_00#e&1f4????f&0&0000#{65e8773d-????-11d0-a3b9-00a0c????196}\global"
[dshow @ 0000000000420680] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 0000000000420680]  "Microfono (Display Audio)"
[dshow @ 0000000000420680]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9??62-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0????CE86}\Microfono (Display Audio)"
[dshow @ 0000000000420680]  "Audio digitale (S/PDIF) (Cirrus"
[dshow @ 0000000000420680]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9??62-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0????CE86}\Audio digitale (S/PDIF) (Cirrus"
```

but if I try:

```
ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i audio="Audio digitale (S/PDIF) (Cirrus" -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 100 -offset_y 200 -video_size 1280x720 -i desktop -vcodec h264 YOUR_NAME_HERE.mp4
```

does **not record audio**.

It should be a problem of **"Stereo Mix" missing** in the my PC, in this case by selecting this I could solve the problem